# What test can I use to compare count data across groups?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, count-data

I've conducted an experiment using seeds from several locations to test their viability. For each location, seeds were classed as viable or non-viable, giving me the total amount of viable and non-viable seeds for each location as my dataset. Now I would like to compare the locations to see if there is any significant difference in the viability between them, but I am getting stuck on which test or model (eg binomial model, glm etc) to use and how I might plot these results. Any help would be appreciated!

| location | viable | non-viable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | 35 |
| 2 | 66 | 24 |
| 3 | 67 | 23 |
| 4 | 59 | 31 |
| 5 | 37 | 53 |

Comment: Is this your real / full dataset?  We typically use the name "count data" to refer to non-negative whole numbers without a known upper bound.  These are counts in some sense, but of which of two categories a known total number of seeds falls into.  If you have no covariates, etc, you can test these with a chi-squared test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(We typically use the name "count data" to refer to non-negative whole numbers without a known upper bound. These are counts in some sense, but of which of two categories a known total number of seeds falls into.)*

If you have no covariates, etc., you can test these with a chi-squared test.  You could make a plot, but these are straightforward enough that I think a table of row-wise proportions would be sufficient to communicate this to others.  Here is an example, coded in R:

```r
d = read.table(text="location     viable    non-viable
  1     55  35
  ...
  5     37  53", header=TRUE)
tab = as.table(as.matrix(d[,2:3]))
round(prop.table(tab, margin=1), digits=3)
#   viable non.viable
# A  0.611      0.389
# B  0.733      0.267
# C  0.744      0.256
# D  0.656      0.344
# E  0.411      0.589
chisq.test(tab)
# 
#   Pearson's Chi-squared test
# 
# data:  tab
# X-squared = 28.101, df = 4, p-value = 1.19e-05
```